# Flutter: radio button not updating state in RadioListTile inside showCupertinoModalPopup

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

I use **RadioListTile** inside **showCupertinoModalPopup**

By clicking the unselected radio button in **RadioListTile** inside **showCupertinoModalPopup** is not updated like selected.

Code:

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreen createState() => _MainScreen();
}

class _MainScreen extends State<MainScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('My App'),),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.search),
        onPressed: () {
          _showDatePicker(context);   // OPEN CUPERTINO MODAL POPUP
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  // CUPERTINO MODAL POPUP
  void _showDatePicker(BuildContext context) {
    showCupertinoModalPopup(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return CupertinoActionSheet(
          title: const Text('Pick a time'),
          actions: <Widget>[
              Material(
                child: Column(
                  // build RadioListTile
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _myRadioButton("Option 1", 0, (newValue) => setState(() => _groupValue = newValue!)),
                    _myRadioButton("Option 2", 1, (newValue) => setState(() => _groupValue = newValue!),),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 150.0,
                child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                use24hFormat: true,
                onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDateTime) {},
              ),
            ),
          ],
          cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
            child: const Text('Cancel'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _myRadioButton(String title, int value, Function(int?) onChanged) {
    return RadioListTile(
      value: value,
      groupValue: _groupValue,
      onChanged: onChanged,  
      title: Text(title),
    );
  }
}
```

I click to toggle, but nothing happens.
How state radio button in **CupertinoActionSheet** after clicking?

Comment: Where do you get _groupValue from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `StatefulBuilder` to update dialog ui.

```dart
  void _showDatePicker(BuildContext context) {
    showCupertinoModalPopup(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState) =>  //this , setState, you may like to rename it and also call state class setState to reflect the main ui
          CupertinoActionSheet(
            title: const Text('Pick a time'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              Material(
                child: Column(
                  // build RadioListTile
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _myRadioButton("Departure", 0,
                        (newValue) => setState(() => _groupValue = newValue!)),
                    _myRadioButton(
                      "Arrival",
                      1,
                      (newValue) => setState(() => _groupValue = newValue!),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 150.0,
                child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                  initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                  use24hFormat: true,
                  onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDateTime) {},
                ),
              ),
            ],
            cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
              child: const Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```